# how to replace a special character with another special character using php syntax

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace

Please I want to replace comma I.e `,` if found in the `$_POST['address']` with `space | space` using `str_replace()` or `preg_replace()` . Like:

```
$ofa = $_POST['address']
$ofa = str_replace or preg_replace
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$ofa = str_replace(',', ' | ', $_POST['address']);
```

You can read about it here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Answer (score 1):

You need to do sth like this:

```
$address = "some , data , from , post"; // $_POST['address']
$cleanAddress = str_replace(",", " | ", $address);
```